# Pymodbus/Twisted Asynchronous Client Reconnecting

Tags: python, tcp, twisted, modbus, modbus-tcp

I have written a test code which reads some coils/registers from a PLC's modbus server. When I call one request the code works. I unplugged the cable then Twisted calls clientConnectionLost function so my client will reconnected, when I plugged back the cable. If I do multiple requests, like in the code below, the handling breaks, nothing happens. I don't know what causes the problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol,defer
from pymodbus.constants import Defaults
from pymodbus.client.async import ModbusClientProtocol

from time import sleep

def logger():
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig()
    log = logging.getLogger()
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger()

class MyModbusClientProtocol(ModbusClientProtocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        ModbusClientProtocol.connectionMade(self)
        print 'Connected'
        self.read()

    def read(self):
        deferred = self.read_coils(0,1999)
        deferred.addCallbacks(self.requestFetched,self.requestNotFetched)
        deferred = self.read_holding_registers(0,124)
        deferred.addCallbacks(self.requestFetched,self.requestNotFetched)

    def requestNotFetched(self,error):
        print error
        sleep(0.5)

    def requestFetched(self,response):
        try:
            print ("Fetched %d" % response.getRegister(1))
        except:
            print ("Fetched %d" % response.getBit(1))

        self.factory.counter += 1
        if self.factory.counter == 2:
            self.factory.counter = 0
            reactor.callLater(0,self.read)

class MyModbusClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    """A factory.

    A new protocol instance will be created each time we connect to the server.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        p = MyModbusClientProtocol()
        p.factory = self
        return p

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print "connection lost:", reason
        connector.connect()

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "connection failed:", reason
        connector.connect()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    factoryinstance = MyModbusClientFactory()

    reactor.connectTCP("192.168.2.69", 502, factoryinstance)

    reactor.run()
```

Comment: I have a little trouble following the problem you're describing.  Are you saying that if you issue two requests and then unplug the cable, `clientConnectionLost` is not called?  This in contrast with the behavior when you issue only one request and then unplug the cable, which does cause `clientConnectionLost` to be called?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, the two questions what you asked, is the two situation. I am reading the server in a loop with reactor callLater. I'm testing the reconnecting capability with unplugging the cable. With one deferred callback works. Two or more deferred callback not works.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code and believe that you have seen a timing related *red herring* when your code was seen to work after commenting out one of your requests. The behavior you are seeing where `clientConnectionLost` is not called is covered in the twisted FAQ: [Why isn't my connectionLost method called?](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#WhyisntmyconnectionLostmethodcalled)

What you need to do is create your own protocol specific timeout as you can't always rely on TCP's timeouts to work in your favor. A simple way to fix your code would be to add this to the end of your `read` method:

```
self.timeout = reactor.callLater(5, self.transport.abortConnection)
```

Which will abort the connection after 5 seconds wait. You also need to cancel this timeout when your requests have completed successfully with:

```
self.timeout.cancel()
```

in your `requestFetched` method before you call your `read` again.